# Как воспроизвести видео без задержек?

Tags: android, videoview

Есть нарезка из маленьких видео для отображения персонажа на сцене. Использую компонент VideoView для отображения этих видео, но при переключении между ними, происходит небольшая, но заметная задержка. В чем может быть проблема и можно ли это исправить в VideoView или если перейти на MediaPlayer?
Код воспроизведения видео ниже:

```
        public void load(Uri _videoUri) {
            videoUri = _videoUri;
            videoPlayer.setVideoURI(_videoUri);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            Log.d("Scene", "onPrepared");
            videoPlayer.start();
        }
```

Comment: возможно стоит поиграться с многопоточностью, пока одно видео воспроизводится, второе грузится. так же советую глянуть на ExoPlayer. там и перфоманс хороший и кеширование есть